# deleting list of records with linq-to-sql

Tags: c#, linq-to-sql

I'm writing a linq-to-sql query to delete a list of records: I pass in a list of RecordID and I want the corresponding records deleted.

This is what I have so far:

```
public void DeleteMyRecords(List<long> TheRecordIDs)
{
   using (TheDC MyDC = new TheDC()) //TheDC is the DataContext 
   {
       MyDC.DeleteOnSubmit(from a in MyDC.TheTable
                           where TheRecordIDs.Contains(a.RecordID)
                           select a).SubmitChanges(); 
   }
}
```

For now, I see the `DeleteOnSubmit` underlined in red. How do you write such query so that it works?

Thanks for your help.

Comment: what's the error you're getting?

Comment: The error is "TheDC does not contain a definition for DeleteOnSubmit"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As query may return more then one record you may need to call `DeleteAllOnSubmit`

```
var records = from a in MyDC.TheTable
                           where TheRecordIDs.Contains(a.RecordID)
                           select a;

MyDC.TheTables.DeleteAllOnSubmit(records); 
MyDc.SubmitChanges();
```

Comment: I'm still getting the same "TheDC does not contain a definition for DeleteAllOnSubmit". And BTW, you're are right that since there's more than one record, I should indeed be using the DeleteAll function.

Comment: Updated my answer, please give it a try.

Comment: BTW, what happens when some of the RecordIDs passed in as parameter are not in the table?

Comment: They will be ignored as query is supposed to return the matched items, you better test it your self.